# Sitecore 7.1 Media Library Attach to existing item does not work

Tags: flash, content-management-system, sitecore, media-library, sitecore7.1

This problem occurs throughout various Sitecore 7.1 installations that we have, including clean installations with an existing database. It occurs in Chrome, Firefox and IE10, so far as we have tested. We have installations on Windows 7 local machines as well as Windows Server 2012 servers.

When editing an existing image in the media library, we can choose Attach and the "Attach a File" dialog comes up. Now, when pressing the "Browse" button to find a file, nothing occurs. Nothing is logged in the sitecore logs and no js errors show up in the console. Nothing happens.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same problem I wrote to Sitecore support,and they registered it like a known bug on Sitecore 7.1 Initial Release . They suggest me to implement the workaround described [here](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/ReleaseNotes/KnownIssues%20Recommended/Flash%20upload%20limitations.aspx):

Comment: I updated the web.config setting "Upload.Classic" (as suggested in the link) to a value of "true" and it switched to the HTML version and everything now works. It uses the HTML version, but that is completely fine with me. Thank-you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions to this problem.

**Solution #1** 
The problem is fixed in Update-1 (rev. 140130) for Sitecore version 7.1 and you can read more about it here:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%207/ReleaseNotes/ChangeLog/Release%20History%20SC71.aspx

> Issues resolved - Media Library When you clicked the Attach button on
>   a media item and then clicked Browse, nothing happened. This has been
>   fixed. (395494, 398762)

**Solution #2**
Use sitecore climber's suggestion above to disable the flash uploader. For those that want a quick cut-paste solution for their custom config patches, use the following:

```
<setting name="Upload.Classic">
    <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```